# Find a circle circle tangent using an iterative, numerical, method

Tags: matlab, geometry, octave, numerical-methods

[image: circle circle tangents]

Given: centers and radii of two circles

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to use a numerical method to find a circle circle tangent. Using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleTangents.html I would have some idea of how to solve it by hand but no idea how to do so using matlab/octave.

It is setting up the problem that causes me difficulties. Namely creating the system of equations. On the website above they use the fact that the dot product between the line from the center to the tangent-point is perpendicular to the tangential line. However, I have no idea of how I would translate this into my model. If I used matlab's "dot" function, how would I set up the Jacobian matrix?

Comment: Do you need to implement the numerical method by yourself? If not, the MATLAB function `fsolve()` may help you. 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html

Comment: I don't think your problem is the numerical method. If you can't set up the equations, you have nothing to solve numerically.

Comment: Why do you want an iterative solution when a closed formula is available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using MATLAB built-in functions**

The simplest way to do it would be to define the function as it is, then use the `fsolve()` function. For example (the code is not tested):

```
function y = cctang(t)
    %t is a 1-by-4 line vector (first two members = t1, last two members = t2)
    %y is a 1-by-4 vector

    %Initialization of centers and radii
    x1 = [0 0]; r1=4;
    x2 = [1 1]; r2=0.5;

    y= zeros(1, 4);

    y(1) = ( t(3:4) - x2) * ( t(3:4) - t(1:2))';
    y(2) = ( t(1:2) - x1) * ( t(3:4) - t(1:2))';
    y(3) = norm(t(1:2)-x1)^2 - r1^2;
    y(4) = norm(t(3:4)-x2)^2 - r2^2;

end
```

And then the execution:

```
t0 = [0 0 1 1];
solution = fsolve(@cctang,t0);
```

**Using custom iterative function**

If you want to build everything from scratch, you can build a custom Jacobian function and input it to the solving function you gave in the question. The Jacobian function should look like:

```
function  J = myJacobian(t)
    %returns a 4-by-4 matrix
    x1 = [0 0]; r1=4;
    x2 = [1 1]; r2=0.5;

    J = zeros(4,4);

    J(1,:) = [ x2(1)-t(3), x2(2)-t(4), 2*t(3)-x2(1), 2*t(4)-x2(2)];
    %etc...
end
```

**Using Symbolic Toolbox**

Much of the "hard work" in the previous method comes from the fact that you need to compute the derivatives numerically and manually.
Using the Symbolic Toolbox, you can symbolically define the function, and then use the [built-in `jacobian()` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/jacobian.html) to compute the Jacobian matrix.

Those would be the input to your custom numeric solving function. At each iteration you should substitute the symbolic variables with the actual numeric values (see [`subs()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html)).

This will make your code much more general and less sensitive to human errors (for example, what is the probability I made a mistake in the *one* derivative I computed in the last block of code?).

Answer (score 2):

"Deflate" the two circles until one becomes a point. During the deflation, the outer tangents keep the same direction.

To find the two tangents to a circle of radius `R` from a point at distance `D` from the center, it suffices to solve a right triangle. In particular, the position angle of the contact point wrt the centerline is given by `sin(phi)=R/D`.

The two inner tangents are found by similarly inflating the larger circle.

[image]

UPDATE: easy analytical solution.

Without loss of generality, let the deflated circle be centered at the origin with unit radius (apply translation and scaling). Let `(U, V)` the external point and `(X, Y)` a point on the circle (such that `X²+Y²=1`).

We express orthogonality of the tangent with the radius vector by a dot product, `U . (U - X) + Y . (V - Y) = 0, i.e. U . X + V . Y = 1`.

Let us normalize by dividing by `√(U² + V²)` to yield `u . X + v . Y = t`, which we rewrite `(v . Y)² = (t - u . X)²`, or `X² - 2 u . t . X + t² - v² = 0`.

The solution is simply

```
X = u . t +/- v . √(1 - t²)
Y = v . t -/+ u . √(1 - t²)
```

Multiplying by the radii of the two original circles, you obtain the vectors from the centers to the contact points.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Yellow's solution, I want to point out that the problem can be solved with a more geometric flavor of iteration.  This solution generalizes to any smooth curves, not just circles.

Let's call the circles `C[A]` and `C[B]` with centers `A` and `B` respectively and radii `R[A]` and `R[B]`.  The square brackets indicate subscripts.

You're also have some initial estimates of the line endpoints, possibly from user picks.  Call these points `P[A][0]` and `P[B][0]`.

[image: One iteration]

For `P[A][i]` and `P[B][i]`, compute `P[A][i+1]` and `P[B][i+1]` as follows:

1. Create a line `L[i]` by projecting `P[A][i]` and `P[B][i]` onto the circle.
2. Let `Q[A][i]` be the nearest point on `L[i]` to `A`.
3. Let `Q[B][i]` similarly be the nearest point on `L[i]` to `B`.
4. Let `P[A][i+1]` be the projection of `Q[A][i]` onto `C[A]`.
5. Let `P[B][i+1]` be the projection of `Q[B][i]` onto `C[B]`.
6. If `||P[A][i+1] - Q[A][i]|| + ||P[A][i+1] - Q[A][i]|| < epsilon`, the line segment `P[A][i+1], P[B][i+1]` is your solution.